# Keyboard events not responding on page load until click occurs (using jquery hotkeys or mousetrap)

Tags: jquery, hotkeys, shortcut

I have tried using the jquery hotkeys library (https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) and the mousetrap library (http://craig.is/killing/mice) to handle keyboard shortcuts on my site.

However, right when the page is loaded, even though I try binding to document or window, no events trigger. Once I click, then the events trigger. I have tried forcing a click initially using jQuery as a hack... but it isn't quite working.

Should keyboard events respond right on page load? Do they only start responding once the users has focused on the page? Is there a way to make these bind to the document before a user click with the mouse?

I have tried focusing using `.focus()` and `.click()` and seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565988/jquery-keyup-not-fired-until-user-clicks-page-first), but not luck.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround? I'm seeing the same issue and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard events only fire when an element on the page (most likely an input) has been focused.

Here is a similar post:

[Do browser key events fire (bubble) only to elements in focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214547/do-browser-key-events-fire-bubble-only-to-elements-in-focus)

Comment: I'd like to listen to key events on the whole document or window. For example, if you load gmail, right away keyboard shortcuts trigger actions. When I try using .focus() or .click() to focus programmatically...I get no events.